# How to move inside else not to catch?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, selenium-webdriver

i am using selenium with java

```
  public void main(String args[]){
    try{
      if(ele.isDisplayed) {
        syso("test1");
      } else {
        syso("test2");
      }
    } catch(Exception e){
      syso("Exception is"+e);
    }
  }
```

First i will check element is visible as default i know it is not visible so
i want to go inside else statement hear
i am not going inside else condition   directly getting exception,
how to go inside else condition? i tried removing try catch block please help.

Comment: You can put the if-else in another try-catch block within the main try block.

Comment: @Sanchita  give me example pls

Comment: -1 for writing conditional tests, i.e, tests with executation path that depends on the entry condition, is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @dzieciou Tell me the way with example

Comment: @sameerjoshi The question is why your element is sometimes visible and sometimes not?

Comment: @dzieciou i am loading differant URL's from excel sheet, for each url iam, checking the element is displayed or not if displayed do some actions else print"Element not visible"

Comment: @sameerjoshi, in such a case I would create two tests: one for URLs without element displayed and another for element *not* displayed. That would make things clearer and give confidence you cover both execution paths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36262/discussion-between-sameer-joshi-and-dzieciou).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you this in If-else way, then you have to write a separate function which will check if element is present or not. Following is the code for same.

```
    try {
        if(isElementDisplayed(ele)) {
            System.out.println("Test1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test2");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
}

public boolean isElementDisplayed(WebElement ele) {
    boolean elementDisplayed = false;

    try {
        ele.isDisplayed();
        elementDisplayed = true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        elementDisplayed = false;
    }

    return elementDisplayed;

}
}
```

In this `isElementDisplayed(WebElement ele)` function will test if element is present and based on that it will return the `boolean` value.

This function will be called from `if` statement.

Comment: Why does the first catch catches any exception of isElementDisplayed does not throw any?

Comment: What is the exception your're trying to catch in second catch statement? `NoSuchElementException`? `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code, you are trying to go test2 when test1 fails.

You can rewrite your code as below

```
try {
try {
ele.isDisplayed
syso("test1")
} catch(Exception e){
syso("test2")
} catch(Exception e) {
syso("Exception is"+e);
}
```

Comment: in your code, there is no if else statement, i developed code using if else statement as you can see above, pls help

Comment: @sameerjoshi for keeping your if-else statement I have added another answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing the exception, but you're probably called `isDisplayed` on an element that is not **present** on the page (which is a subtle difference with being not displayed).

Because the element simply doesn't exist, the `el.isDisplayed` throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

You could, for example, use an [ExpectedCondition](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-).
You can also split the catch block depending on the specific exception, for more custom logic.
This is valid C# code but it's very similar in Java:

```
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
try {
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("bubble-4")));
    syso("test1");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // NoSuchElementException when element does not exist
    // TimeoutException when element exists but is invisible
    syso("test2: " + e.Message);
}
```

Edit: if you really want to hold on to your `if/else` statement, you will have to call a helper function that returns a boolean, and put the above logic in that helper function.

For example:

```
public boolean isVisible(By locator){
    try {
        WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can just call:

```
if(isVisible(By.id("test"))){
    syso("test1");
}
else ...
```

Comment: in your code, there is no if else statement, i developed code using if else statement as you can see above, pls help

Comment: edited my code for if/else in a clean and reusable way

Comment: it always throw an exception only so it wont go inside else condition thats why we use catch block to handle exception

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception if the element is actually visible... That's what you're trying to validate, no? Anyway, do as you please. :)

Comment: No iam trying if not visible then it throws exception

Comment: OK, but your original question sounded differently. :) Either way, glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

Please check my updated answer

```
public void main(String args[]){
try{
    List<WebElement> list =driver.findElements(By.id("ads"));           
    if(list.size() > 0){            
        if(isDisplayed){
            System.out.println("TEST1");
        }else{
            System.out.println("TEST2");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("ELEMENT IS NOT FOUND");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
     syso("Exception is"+e);
}
```

}

Comment: is it go inside else statement ?

Comment: yes, if the element is not visible.For going in to else block first of all element should be present in DOM

Comment: your code is throwing an exception i tried using google website

Comment: what is the exception ???

Comment: NoSuchElementException